# windows phone 8: updating the ui in an async task with the frame passed

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, frame

I would like to update the UI of a frame async.
my workflow is:
Frame =>(Shared) async get data from server => JsonParser => populating textboxes in Frame
The original frame is passed trough the classes.

[image]

Suggestions ?

Comment: Have you heard about MVVM and data bindings? I suggest you look into that. Also `async void` is a big no-no... Also your method does not do anything async.

Comment: I'm learning to program in windows for about 1 full day. so i'm pretty new to this. i will take a look to these things. I tought to do the parsing async ( cause i do that async in andoird ) 
Would it be smart to let the Dataretreiver and the parser return the data so i can update the ui in the mainFrame itself ?

Answer (score 1):

All UI code need to be done in the UI thread which means it cant run asynchronously. If you want to parse your responses asynchronously then use the following code:

```
public static async Task ParseResponse(String response, Frame frame)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            SingleTank parsedTanks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleTank>(response);
        });

        // UI code by calling the dispatcher
    }
```

But if you call this method from a non-UI thread, then you need to use `Dispatcher` to return back to the UI thread when invoking UI code. I hope this helps somehow.